# Container full height minus footer height

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a JS-Draggable div that I'd like to be able to be dragged over the whole screen, minus the footer. Alternatively I'd also later like to be able to "full-size" the draggable object, allowing it to cover the whole screen minus the footer.

For that I am trying to make a content-wrapper of that size (whole screen - footer), however the attempts I tried to follow from other stackoverflow posts didn't seem to work.

Here is the code I have so far:

```js
$( function() {
    $(".draggable").position({
        my: "center",
        at: "center",
        of: ".bg"
    })
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
        scroll: false,
        containment: ".container"
    });
  } );
```

```css
body,html {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

.bg {
  background-image: url("http://abload.de/img/background4mqdx.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.footer {
   width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #C2C5CA inset, 0px 2px 0px 0px #FFF inset;
  background-color: #C2C5CA;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.draggable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="bg">
      <div class="container">
      <div class="draggable">
      content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="footer">
  footer
  </div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: @RenevanderLende I believe you may not have read the question properly. I have no issue with the `draggable` staying inside the parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using:

```
.container {
  height: calc(100vh - 40px); // screen height - footer height
}
```

Comment: @alex careful if you use this, it will mean if your content is too large for the container, it will overflow - you would need to add `overflow: auto` to the container - unless you want the footer to be pushed off screen, then it would be better to go with a flex solution.  Also if your body had a horizontal scrollbar for whatever reason, `100vh` doesn't take that into account